# Getting index values from pd mean() and std() functions

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to get the index values from a pd std().
My final objective is to match the index with another df and insert the corresponding values (standard deviations).

```
(in): df_std['index'] = df_std.index

(out): Index([u'AAPL US Equity', u'QQQ US Equity', u'BRABCBACNPR4 BZ Equity'...dtype='object')
```

However, I've been unable to add the indexes to the "right" of df_std because of the types: df_std.index is a series while df_std is a df. When I try to do it, a line is added instead of a column:

```
(in): df_std['index'] = df_std.index

(out):
BRSTNCLF1R25 Govt                                                   64.0864
BRITUBACNPR1 BZ Equity                                              2.67762
BRSTNCNTB4O9 Govt                                                   48.2419
BRSTNCLF1R74 Govt                                                    64.901
PBR US Equity                                                      0.770755
BRBBASACNOR3 BZ Equity                                              2.93335
BRSTNCLF1R82 Govt                                                   65.0979
index                     Index([u'AAPL US Equity', u'QQQ US Equity', u'...
dtype: object
```

I've already tried converting it df_std.inde to a tuple and to a dataframe.

Thanks!

---

Edit:

I'm trying to match df_std['index'] with df_final['bloomberg_ticker'] and bring the std values to df_final['std']:

```
(in): print df_final
(out):
serie            tipo  tp_cnpjfundo    valor  id        bloomberg_ticker  \
0    NaN           caixa           NaN      NaN   0                     NaN   
1    NaN     titpublicos           NaN      NaN   1       BRSTNCLF1R17 Govt   
2    NaN     titpublicos           NaN      NaN   2       BRSTNCLF1R17 Govt   
3    NaN     titpublicos           NaN      NaN   3       BRSTNCLF1R25 Govt
```

(the column 'id' will be deleted later)

Comment: Just assign the value, series match is by default done when series is assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.reset_index()` than assigning if what you have is a dataframe i.e

```
df_std = df_std.reset_index()
```

Example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0,1,2,3], index=['a','b','c','d'])
df = df.reset_index()
```

Output :

```
    index  0
0     a  0
1     b  1
2     c  2
3     d  3
```

In case what you have is a `series`, convert that to dataframe then reset_index i.e if `df_std` is the series you have then

```
df_std = df_std.to_frame().reset_index()
```

I think what are trying to do is map the values of series to a specific column so you can use

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a','b','c','d','e'],'vales':[5,1,2,4,5]})
s = pd.Series([1,2,3],index=['a','b','c'])

df['new'] = df['col'].map(s)
```

Output :

```
  col  vales  new
0   a      5  1.0
1   b      1  2.0
2   c      2  3.0
3   d      4  NaN
4   e      5  NaN
```

In your case you can use `df_final['index'].map(df_std)`

For conditional check if the index of series is present int he index column of dataframe then you can use .isin i.e

```
df['col'].isin(s.index) # Returns the boolen mask 

df[df['col'].isin(s.index)] #Returns the dataframe based matched index
```

Comment: I think he has a serise , maybe adding `to_frame`

Comment: Thanks @Wen maybe what he has is a series.

Comment: I have to apologize myself: I'm trying to match the index of df_std with a specific column of another dataframe, not just insert them "directly".

The code to to this should be smt. like:
 `df_std[df_final["index"].contains(df_std["index"], na=False)][0]`

right?

Comment: Then what you want mapping `df1['col'].map(df_std)`

Comment: @Bharath thank you very much!
I added the df_final to the question. You helped with my main struggle, though.

Comment: @Rafael Chow Glad can help do vote when you get enough reputation.

Comment: TBH my first thought was merge since u said matching series index I suggested map. Anyway happy coding